# Will I ever have to care about versisining maven modules?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a single application that consists of several modules:

```
app-parent
    app-main
    app-start-cmd
    app-start-gui
    app-tools
        app-tools-toolone
        app-tools-tooltwo
```

`app-main` holds the bigger part of the application's body. `app-start-cmd`, `app-start-gui`, and `app-tools` modules depend on it.

When I was adding this dependency, it asked me for a version of `app-main` that they should depend on, and `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` was entered automatically.

I have two questions:

1. When I change `app-main`'s version, will the dependency in other projects be automatically updated? (Don't want to mess something up right now.)
2. Is there a way to just change the `app-parent`'s version and have it reflect on all other modules? It is after all just one application, even though it will build several separate artifacts for different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try versions-maven-plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/ it can manage versions in multi-module projects. Run this command in main project

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.2.2
```

and it will change all versions to 2.2.2